# Live Paypal Application Id

Tags: paypal

I have implemented standard PayPal payment gateway in my project. When my business account receives payments from the customer after then I have to send payments to vendors/hub. Before sending payments to vendor/hub I want to verify their PayPal account. Means PayPal account is valid or exists or not. Then I will send payments.

I know we have GetVerifiedStatus() API. To use this API I need live app id. If someone has another way, please share with me.

Comment: Have you tried the [PayPal Sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)?

Comment: Yup .. I have tried with Paypal sandbox .. I have used Sandbox app id and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to implement IPN. With IPN, every time a payment is completed, PayPal will post data back to your site regarding the Payment. You can use the variable 'payer_status' to confirm if the buyer has an existing account. If it comes back as verified, means buyer has a verified PayPal account.

Refer to the following links

1. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/
2. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/